# How to check if item exists in Cache (System.Web.Cache)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, system.web.caching

**Hi,**

To check if the key already exists in cache I shoulde be able to do the following :

```
if(Cache["MyKey"] != null)
```

This does however not work? If I create an instance from the Cache class i will be able to get the object this way :

```
cache.Get("MyKey") or cache["MyKey"]
```

But even if I check for null like this :

```
if(cache["MyKey"] != null)
```

It will throw an NullRefException?

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit1 :**

This is how I instansiate the cache

```
private Cache cache
        {
            get {
                if (_cache == null)
                    _cache = new Cache();
                return _cache; }
        }
```

Comment: How are you instantiating the Cache instance? It isnot your key throwing the NRE, is the cache object itself

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Checking for a null value is how to test whether an object for a certain key is in the Cache. Therefore,

```
if(Cache["MyKey"] != null)
```

is correct.

However, you should not instantiate a new Cache object. You may use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache` instead. This is the instance of the Cache and lives in the application domain.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx):

> One instance of this class is created
>   per application domain, and it remains
>   valid as long as the application
>   domain remains active. Information
>   about an instance of this class is
>   available through the Cache property
>   of the HttpContext object or the Cache
>   property of the Page object.

Comment: Problem is when a cached object actually is null, and especially where the query to try to get the data again is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking if the cache is not Null & post that check if the key exists or not (by using .Contains method).

```
if (myCache != null && myCache.Contains("keyName") && myCache.Get("keyName") != null)
        {
            myDS = (DataSet)myCache.Get("keyName");
        }
```